# Why is this displaying weird characters on the console?

Tags: ruby, encoding

Take this text for example:

`the three umlauts are ä, ö, and ü.`.

Let's assume they are in a text file, which I'm reading like this:

```
data = File.read("umlauts.txt")
```

Now, if I try to output them, I get this:

```
the three umlauts are Σ, ÷, and ⁿ.
```

If I write it to a file, they get outputted correctly. How can I make them show up properly on a windows command prompt? I'm using `Ruby 1.8.6`. I want to be able to perform quick debug from the command prompt.

Comment: The encoding used by the command prompt is probably different than the one used in your text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What encoding is the file? I'm guessing probably utf-8. Windows cmd prompt does not use utf-8.

Here's a good article that covers this: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html

Comment: and there's no way to force it do that?

Comment: Not sure but I don't think so. What you can do is convert the encoding before printing the output (or some languages allow you to specify encoding on streams, not sure about ruby).

Comment: @Geo: Maybe switch operating systems? :P

Comment: @Geo: "and there's no way to force it do that" => see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe set a different [code page](http://www.computerhope.com/chcphlp.htm) for cmd?

For explanations on encodings, read [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).